# Why does my IPTables changes not deny access from all IP addresses except CloudFlare’s ranges?

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, iptables, tcp

I am running apache on ubuntu 18.04. I used IPtables to deny access from all IP addressed except CloudFlare’s ranges and when I run iptables -L –line-number I get

```
1 ACCEPT tcp – 131.0.72.0/22 anywhere multiport dports http,https
2 ACCEPT tcp – 172.64.0.0/13 anywhere multiport dports http,https
3 ACCEPT tcp – 104.16.0.0/12 anywhere multiport dports http,https
4 ACCEPT tcp – 162.158.0.0/15 anywhere multiport dports http,https
5 ACCEPT tcp – 198.41.128.0/17 anywhere multiport dports http,https
6 ACCEPT tcp – 197.234.240.0/22 anywhere multiport dports http,https
7 ACCEPT tcp – 188.114.96.0/20 anywhere multiport dports http,https
8 ACCEPT tcp – 190.93.240.0/20 anywhere multiport dports http,https
9 ACCEPT tcp – 108.162.192.0/18 anywhere multiport dports http,https
10 ACCEPT tcp – 141.101.64.0/18 anywhere multiport dports http,https
11 ACCEPT tcp – 103.31.4.0/22 anywhere multiport dports http,https
12 ACCEPT tcp – 103.22.200.0/22 anywhere multiport dports http,https
13 ACCEPT tcp – 103.21.244.0/22 anywhere multiport dports http,https
14 ACCEPT tcp – 173.245.48.0/20 anywhere multiport dports http,https
15 ufw-before-logging-input all – anywhere anywhere
16 ufw-before-input all – anywhere anywhere
17 ufw-after-input all – anywhere anywhere
18 ufw-after-logging-input all – anywhere anywhere
19 ufw-reject-input all – anywhere anywhere
20 ufw-track-input all – anywhere anywhere
21 DROP tcp – anywhere anywhere multiport dports http,https
```

The exact command I ran was:

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports http,https -s 173.245.48.0/20 -j ACCEPT 
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports http,https -s 103.21.244.0/22 -j ACCEPT 
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports http,https -s 103.22.200.0/22 -j ACCEPT 
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports http,https -s 103.31.4.0/22 -j ACCEPT 
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports http,https -s 141.101.64.0/18 -j ACCEPT 
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports http,https -s 108.162.192.0/18 -j ACCEPT 
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports http,https -s 190.93.240.0/20 -j ACCEPT 
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports http,https -s 188.114.96.0/20 -j ACCEPT 
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports http,https -s 197.234.240.0/22 -j ACCEPT 
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports http,https -s 198.41.128.0/17 -j ACCEPT 
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports http,https -s 162.158.0.0/15 -j ACCEPT 
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports http,https -s 104.16.0.0/12 -j ACCEPT 
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports http,https -s 172.64.0.0/13 -j ACCEPT 
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports http,https -s 131.0.72.0/22 -j ACCEPT 


sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports http,https -j DROP
```

Why am I still able to access the website from direct Digitalocean droplet IP address? Thanks

Edit:

```
sudo iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports http,https -s 173.245.48.0/20 -j ACCEPT 
sudo iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports http,https -s 103.21.244.0/22 -j ACCEPT 
sudo iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports http,https -s 103.22.200.0/22 -j ACCEPT 
sudo iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports http,https -s 103.31.4.0/22 -j ACCEPT 
sudo iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports http,https -s 141.101.64.0/18 -j ACCEPT 
sudo iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports http,https -s 108.162.192.0/18 -j ACCEPT 
sudo iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports http,https -s 190.93.240.0/20 -j ACCEPT 
sudo iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports http,https -s 188.114.96.0/20 -j ACCEPT 
sudo iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports http,https -s 197.234.240.0/22 -j ACCEPT 
sudo iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports http,https -s 198.41.128.0/17 -j ACCEPT 
sudo iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports http,https -s 162.158.0.0/15 -j ACCEPT 
sudo iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports http,https -s 104.16.0.0/12 -j ACCEPT 
sudo iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports http,https -s 172.64.0.0/13 -j ACCEPT 
sudo iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports http,https -s 131.0.72.0/22 -j ACCEPT 


sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports http,https -j DROP
```

Comment: Looks like you’re already using UFW. I suggest you stick to it.

Comment: So if I have run the command under "The exact command I ran was:" what exactly would I have to run now to block people's access to direct IP of digitalocean droplet?

Answer (score 0):

You either have the wrong chain (INPUT is for traffic coming to your network) or you are matching by destination port rather then source port.  I suspect you are wanting to use the OUTPUT chain onstead of the INPUT chain to prevent the traffic leaving your PC.

I am assuming also that the IP address of the droplet is not in one of the ranges you specifically allowed.

Comment: I just want deny access from all IP addresses except CloudFlare’s ranges in order to not be able to access the website from direct Digitalocean droplet IP address @davidgo

Comment: Change the INPUT rules to OUTPUT rules then.

Comment: Thanks. @davidgo should I leave the current rules though?

Comment: Just run what I added in the question edit?

Comment: Yes, but I overlooked something. You also need to change the -s IP to -d IP

Comment: It seems like OP is asking about server-side firewall rules and you're answering about client-side ones?

Comment: @,user1686 yes - the question is very vague. The rule change is the same in either case, although I do fear he has the destination ports reversed with the source ports (but I've answered what he actually asked as implied by " able to access the website from direct Digitalocean droplet IP"

Comment: So if I have run the command under "The exact command I ran was:" what exactly would I have to run now to block people's access to direct IP of digitalocean droplet? @davidgo

Comment: It worked My ufw was interfering with iptables. @davidgo But I did not need to hange the -s IP to -d IP  or Change the INPUT rules to OUTPUT rules then